# Why is a partial named "next" not working in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app I recently tried to use a partial named `_next.html.erb` which simply contains a link to the next record:

```
<%= link_to_neighbor('next', @company) %>
```

I then tried to render that partial in my `show` and `edit` views:

```
<%= render 'companies/actions/next' %>
```

However, that kept giving me an error which I was unable to track down:

```
/app/views/companies/actions/_next.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end ..._buffer = @output_buffer;next = local_assigns[:next];;@outpu...
```

What really struck me was the fact that there was in fact no **syntax error** in the partial. The syntax is absolutely fine.

I wasn't able to get this partial working until I renamed it from `_next.html.erb` to `_nnnext.html.erb`.

So I guess *next* is some kind of reserved word in Rails or Ruby?

According to [this list](http://bparanj.blogspot.de/2011/07/reserved-words-in-rails.html) it's not, though!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`next` is a Ruby keyword. Add all such keywords to the list of things you shouldn't name partials in Rails.

Because of RoR's wonderful "configuration by convention", all partials get a local variable named after the partial, containing its payload. So to run your partial, Rails evaluated `next = local_assigns[:next]` But the `next` on the left looks like a keyword, so >kaboom!<

Comment: Yes, I just found the solution myself: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/1140-partials-named-_next-crash-render. The error I got didn't provide any clue on how to fix this, though. Definitely not nice!

Comment: Here is a list of Ruby's reserved words: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Language-Basics/Rubysreservedwords.htm